# How can I deselect a button after 2 buttons have been selected JToggleButton

Tags: java

I am trying to make sure that in my memory game, once a person selects two cards. They are visible, as soon as they select a third card, the first two cards are no longer visible.

Here follows my implementation of the ActionPerformed method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     cardsSelected++;

     int row=0;
     int column=0;
     int row2=0;
     int column2=0;
     if(cardsSelected == 3){
     card1.setSelected(false);
     card2.setSelected(false);
     card1 = null;
     card2 = null;

     cardsSelected = 1;

     }
     if(card1 == null){
       card1 = (Cell) e.getSource();
       card1.setSelected(true);
       row = card1.getRow(); 
       column = card1.getColumn();
       board[row][column].setIcon2();
       }
     else if(card2 == null){
      card2 = (Cell) e.getSource();    
      card2.setSelected(true);
       row = card2.getRow(); 
       column = card2.getColumn();
       board[row][column].setIcon2();
     }

     if(card1 != null && card2 != null){
     numTries++;

     if(card1.sameType(card2) ){


       row = card1.getRow(); 
       column = card1.getColumn();      
       row2 = card2.getRow();
       column2 = card2.getRow();     
       if(row != row2 && column != column2){
       board[row][column].setVisible(false);
       board[row2][column2].setVisible(false);
       card1=null;
       card2=null;
       }
     }


     }         
        }
```

Any insight will be very welcome!
Thank you all in advance!
Mjall2

Comment: Myself, I would use a Swing Timer to display the incorrect selection pair for XX milliseconds and then cover them up. This is how most of these types of games run and allows the user to re-select an item that had just been selected. Also, consider improving your "creative" indentation. It's not just to make your code look pretty, but it helps others (in other words *us*) understand your code better.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be convenient to use the button's selected state to indicate whether to show or hide a card, then you can use the enabled state to indicate that a pair has been matched and is out of play. There's a related example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

Comment: @trashgod
I tried to decipher the code however, my problem is that using a JToggleButton, once I select a card, the blue border around it appears and it doesn't go away unless i click on the card again. I'd like for it to go away once i click on the third card.

Comment: @Mjall2: `checkMatch()` handles this by adding the third button to `selected` and removing/de-selecting the previous two.