# Can't flip cards in card matching program java

Tags: java

I'm writing a card matching program in java but I ran into a wall,. My object is to have all the cards displayed facedown on the screen, when the user clicks on a card it should flip faceup and wait for another to be clicked and also be turned faceup. After two cards have been turned it should check to see if they are equal and clear them from the screen, if not they should flip back facedown. My problem is when I flip the second card it immediately checks to see if they are equal or not so it doesn't even look like it flipped giving the user no time to look at it. I've excluded the code that checks if they are equal since I already have that correct

```
 int count = 0;
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
{
    //check if click occurred on one of the cards, if so flip card
    for(int x=0; x<20; x++)                    //check the 20 cards
    {
        if(cardList.get(x).contains(me.getX(), me.getY()))
        {
            count++;              //count is increased with each click
            cardList.get(x).flip();                       //flip the card
            repaint();                      
            flipCard(x, cardList.get(x).number, count); 
        }
    }
}

public void flipCard(int card, int value, int counter)
{
    int cardNum = card;
    int cardVal = value;
    count = counter;

    if (count == 2)          //if count is two it should check if they are equal
    {
        for(int x=0; x<20; x++)  //if wrong flip them all back
        {
            cardList.get(x).flipAll();
        }
    }
    count = 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: You need to put a statement in there that waits for a specified amount of time... I suggest it should happen when you actually have two cards face up, and you have checked whether they are equal or not. Before taking action, you wait a couple of seconds. Do you know how to do that? Hint - look at `Thread.sleep(ms)`...

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9491295/230513).

Comment: I've already tried sleep but it won't work for some reason. It sleeps when I click on the card, before it flips faceup, then it resumes. And it's not a matter of placing it before the flip because I've placed it everywhere and it still does that :/